# Why do i need library file with -sources suffix?

Tags: java, libraries

I don't understand why there are often two files in libraries, one with `-sources` suffix.

Here's what i mean

[image: two files]

Comment: That's the 'source' part in "open source"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sources are useful if you want to step into the library when debugging. You don't *need* them, but they might save you if you can't understand why the library behaves in a certain way.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer below, the -source archive is the actual source code, while the other file is the compiled version of it.